# Laravel Valet - This Site Can't Be Reached

Tags: macos, laravel-valet

I have successfully followed the Setup a Mac Dev Machine until this tutorial: https://laracasts.com/series/setup-a-mac-dev-machine-from-scratch/episodes/10?autoplay=true

The problem is that when I go to `SITENAME.dev`, nothing shows up. Instead, I get the following message:

`This site can’t be reached`

`test2.dev` refused to connect. Did you mean http://test2.de/? Search Google for test2 dev `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`

I've tried this both for a laravel install (using the laravel installer) and a wordpress install. Neither one works.

Any idea why it is not working. I have followed the course step-by-step as well as the comments. For instance, I modified the `.zshrc` file as follows based on the course and comments:

```
export PATH=$HOME/bin:/usr/local/bin:$HOME/.composer/vendor/bin:$PATH
```

And, in case it is relevant, I am on Mac Sierra (freshly updated).

In short, where Jeffrey is able to get a home page of laravel, I get an error.

Any idea how to fix this?

Thanks.

Comment: Make sure you're going to `http://yoursite.test` instead of `https://yoursite.test` that got me. Assuming you haven't done the valet secure set up (https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/valet#securing-sites)

Answer (score 32):

Go to your site folder and execute the following commands:

```
cd your_project
composer global update
valet uninstall
rm -rf ~/.valet
rm -rf ~/.config/valet
valet install
valet link
valet open
```

It fixed this issue for me, and particularly after PHP upgrades.

Comment: Thanks, this works for me, actually updating composer and restarting valet resolve my issue

Answer (score 3):

Solution:

```
composer global update
brew upgrade nginx
cd your_project
valet start
```

For more details read this blog
https://medium.com/@panjeh/valet-this-site-cant-be-reached-err-connection-refused-ad424ea1e343

Comment: The `brew upgrade nginx` line solved my issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Mac os mojave - version 10.14,
cd in your-project-folder-name and run
valet secure your-project-folder-name

Comment: My .htaccess was forcing the https urls. So default http url was not working. Running `valet secure folder-name` helped

Answer (score 0):

Have you actually started the valet service? Head over to the directory that you ran

```
$valet park
```

in, I'm assuming it's where you've also placed your project and type:

```
$valet start
```

into the terminal. That works for me.

Comment: Is your laravel project definitely called 'test2' and in the directory that you've set parked valet? Another thing to check is that your install is using the .dev extension

    $valet domain

Comment: Yes, the project is definitely called test2 (I've done different tests with different names).  I am sure that I've parked my Sites directory (where test2 is located).  And I just ran valet domain and it came back dev (so it is using the .dev extension).

Comment: Have you searched the Laracasts forum for answers too? Sounds like you’re doing everything right, but someone else may have had a similar issue

Comment: I posted on both the laracasts forum as well as the laravel/valet github issues forum.  I haven't heard from them yet.  I'm wondering if the problem is with Sierra.  Either way - thanks for your help :).

Comment: I’m also on Sierra. Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

Be sure you're over http://app.test and not https://app.test

Laravel Valet uses Not secure http as default.

By the way if you want to secure your app then use

```
valet secure YOURAPPNAME
```

Answer (score 0):

Deleting the file (`sudo rm /etc/resolver/dev`) will clear this issue up.

Answer (score 0):

IF valet is trying to open a HTTPS (SSL connection) type command line in your terminal

```
valet secure
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply running valet restart command solved my problem. I think the Dnsmasq needs to be restarted which the following command does by itself.

```
valet restart
```