# Connection refused on port 80 on Laravel Valet site

Tags: laravel, connection, valet

I've been trying get my Laravel Valet to work again (after working with Vagrant and vue-cli it stopped working). Have resinstalled it many times. Nothing else is running on port :80, and it doesn't help when changing the port to something else.

(But maybe been doing it wrong?)

When I'm running 
`curl -IL http://example.test/`
I get "curl: (7) Failed to connect to example.test port 80: Connection refused"

Any ideas how to proceed?

Comment: did you manage to fix this @erica

Comment: @CodeBoyCode no, not yet :/

Comment: have a look through this thread - it might help :) - 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48053339/laravel-valet-sites-connection-refused-on-port-80

Comment: @CodeBoyCode yeah got the same problem. Ping it works great. But the answer have I already tried with no luck

Comment: do you still have vagrant installed? it might be worth choosing one or the other deleting all of them and starting again from scratch - probably a conflict somewhere, I remember I had it once when I had both installed - can't remember how I fixed it, messaging a friend who helped me now, to see what he recommends :)

Comment: are you managing to use php artisan serve in the meantime?

Comment: I would verify if Iptable or other firewall services are running and what is their configuration and eventually look what is showing with a tail /var/log/messages

Comment: @CodeBoyCode yeah i still have vagrant installed. Really dont want to delete it because it was so hard to install. But if there's no other way then thats a must... I'm not using php artisan serve. Should I?

Comment: @P.Lion when I do the tail I get back "no such file or directory" :)

Comment: @Erica - if youwant to work on your site in the short time go into the terminal and cd your project folder and run php artisan serve and it should load up localhost:8000 and you can atleast run stuff for now

Comment: @CodeBoyCode That's not working due to it's not a laravel project :/

Comment: @Erica what type of project is it?

Comment: @CodeBoyCode It's a Wordpress projekt! And my example is just a plain html site just for test

Comment: Probably you are on Ubuntu or similar distro, so tail /var/log/syslog should do the work

Comment: @P.Lion I'm on a Mac :)

Comment: @P.Lion This is my output, do it look fine? 

Jan 31 14:21:52 --- last message repeated 1 time ---
Jan 31 14:21:52 Ericas-iMac com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (homebrew.mxcl.mysql@5.7[29278]): Service exited with abnormal code: 1
Jan 31 14:21:52 Ericas-iMac com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (homebrew.mxcl.mysql@5.7): Service only ran for 0 seconds. Pushing respawn out by 10 seconds.
Jan 31 14:22:02 Ericas-iMac com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.xpc.launchd.domain.system): Session adoption is only allowed in user domains.

Comment: That is saying that the service MySQL, the database used to store app information, cannot be started. If you have a data .dmp somewhere to recover the easiest way to have it back working is to remove and perform a clean new install install 
https://stefan.magnuson.co/articles/osx/reinstalling-mysql-on-osx-with-homebrew/ BEWARE OF: "complete removal of the existing MySQL installation, including any databases"

Comment: @P.Lion still got the same output :)